# What's wrong with this unused LPCTSTR variable?

Tags: c++

It just declared a unused LPCTSTR variable but the result is different.

if i remove unused variable then won't run.

can you tell me why it won't run?

if it failed, show `Call to RegisterClassEx failed!` alert.

`main.cpp`

```cpp
INT CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow) {
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

    SB_SANDBOX::client* test_client = new SB_SANDBOX::client(hInstance);

    test_client->initApp();
    test_client->initInstance();
    test_client->run();

    return 0;
};
```

`another cpp files`

```cpp
VOID SB_SANDBOX::client::initApp() {

    WNDCLASSEX TESTWNDCLASS;
    TESTWNDCLASS.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    TESTWNDCLASS.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    TESTWNDCLASS.lpfnWndProc = this->publicWndProc;
    TESTWNDCLASS.cbClsExtra = 0;
    TESTWNDCLASS.cbWndExtra = 0;
    TESTWNDCLASS.hInstance = this->get_processHandle();
    TESTWNDCLASS.hIcon = LoadIcon(this->get_processHandle(), IDI_APPLICATION);
    TESTWNDCLASS.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    TESTWNDCLASS.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    TESTWNDCLASS.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    TESTWNDCLASS.lpszClassName = this->get_lpClassName();
    TESTWNDCLASS.hIconSm = LoadIcon(TESTWNDCLASS.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&TESTWNDCLASS)) {
        MessageBox(nullptr,
                   _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
                   _T("Windows Desktop"),
                   0);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Window register class successful!" << '\n';
    };
};

VOID SB_SANDBOX::client::initInstance()
{
    this->wndHandle = CreateWindow(this->get_lpClassName()
, this->get_lpWndName()
, WS_OVERLAPPED
, CW_USEDEFAULT
, CW_USEDEFAULT
, 500, 500,
 nullptr, 0,
 this->get_processHandle(), 0
);
    ShowWindow(this->get_wndHandle(),1);
    UpdateWindow(this->get_wndHandle());
};

INT CALLBACK SB_SANDBOX::client::run()
{
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        this->afterMessageDispatch();
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



SB_SANDBOX::client::client(HINSTANCE hin) {
    const TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");
    LPCTSTR ____________________________________wowowowowow = szWindowClass;
    const TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour Application");

    this->lpClassName = szWindowClass;
    this->lpWndName = szTitle;
    this->processHandle = hin;
};

SB_SANDBOX::client::~client() {
    //delete this->loader;
};

LPCTSTR &SB_SANDBOX::client::get_lpClassName() {
    return this->lpClassName;
};

LPCTSTR &SB_SANDBOX::client::get_lpWndName() {
    return this->lpWndName;
};

HWND &SB_SANDBOX::client::get_wndHandle() {
    return this->wndHandle;
};

HINSTANCE &SB_SANDBOX::client::get_processHandle() {
    return this->processHandle;
};
```

Comment: Probably not the problem but `____________________________________wowowowowow` is an illegal name and is UB to have.  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: What does "won't run" mean? Crash? Error message? Compile error?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Improved. thanks

Comment: @RetiredNinja fail RegisterClassEx function

Comment: `return this->lpClassName;` Where does that variable get initialized? Your constructor ignores the parameter and declares 3 local variables that immediately go out of scope.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I erased some code while trying to minimalize it. Added now.

Comment: @juwonBae, How does that function fail. There's an error code you need to include per the documentation, not just the fact that it failed.

Comment: What is the unused variable?   What is the line of code you are asking about?